# Why do I get a parse error when running this PHP code?

Tags: php

Im new to PHP programming.
I get this error when running the following PHP code to generate a URL.
Im using PHP 5.3.5.

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in
>   C:\wamp\www\test\urlgen.php on line 30

```
function bg_gen_secure_uri(
    'http://demo.com/abc/secure/movie/movie-full-film_256x144-150.mp4',
    'MqG9$fso2lt7(',
    $expiry = 0,
    $allowed_countries = '',
    $disallowed_countries = '',
    $allowed_ip = '',
    $allowed_useragent = '',
    $allowed_metros = '',
    $disallowed_metros = '', $progressive_start = '', $progressive_end = '',
    $extra_params = '' )
{
      return $url;
}
```

I will be very thankful if I get an answer.

Comment: Well, it's all mangled, innit.

Comment: na any  variable set  for 'http://demo.com/abc/secure/movie/movie-full-film_256x144-150.mp4' and 'MqG9$fso2lt7(' and php start with <?php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you giving two constants as parameters?

```
'http://demo.com/abc/secure/movie/movie-full-film_256x144-150.mp4','MqG9$fso2lt7(',
```

That part is wrong. Assign using something, may be like this:

```
<?php
    function bg_gen_secure_uri($p1 = 'http://demo.com/abc/secure/movie/movie-full-film_256x144-150.mp4', $p2 = 'MqG9$fso2lt7(', $expiry = 0, $allowed_countries = '',$disallowed_countries = '', $allowed_ip = '', $allowed_useragent = '',
    $allowed_metros = '',
    $disallowed_metros = '', $progressive_start = '', $progressive_end = '',
    $extra_params = '')


    {

     return $url;
    }
?>
```

And there's no `<php>` tag. Remove that!

Answer (score 1):

You function parameters must be variables, and for default values, you must use like this:

```
<?php
function bg_gen_secure_uri (
$ca='http://demo.com/abc/secure/movie/movie-full-film_256x144-150.mp4',
$b='MqG9$fso2lt7(', 
$expiry = 0, 
$allowed_countries = '',
$disallowed_countries = '', 
$allowed_ip = '', 
$allowed_useragent = '',
$allowed_metros = '',
$disallowed_metros = '', 
$progressive_start = '', 
$progressive_end = '',
$extra_params = ''
)

{

 return $url;

}
echo bg_gen_secure_uri();
?>
```